# Add numbers in JAVA

Tags: java, numbers, addition

How do I add the deposit numbers? Do I need some kind of loop (I´m new to JAVA)?.

```
public class BankAccount {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        BankAccount account = new BankAccount();

        account.deposit(1000, "Deposit 1"); 
        account.deposit(2000, "Deposit 2");
        System.out.println("Balance: " + account.getBalance()); 
        account.deposit(3000, "Deposit 3"); 
        account.deposit(4000, "Deposit 4");
        System.out.println("Balance: " + account.getBalance());
    }

    private int currentBalance = 0;
private int getBalance() {

    int finalBalance = depositAmount + currentBalance;
    return finalBalance;
}

private int depositAmount;

public void deposit(int depositAmount) {

        this.depositAmount = depositAmount;
} 
}
```

Result should be:

Balance: 3000

Balance: 10000

Comment: What is the result you get? What is happening inside account / what does deposit do?

Comment: You need them if you feel so!

Comment: Yeah we know what the result should be.. So what did you say your question was?

Comment: Updated it. I´m new to Java, so be nice :) This is all I have right now. Any ideas?

Comment: You said result should be 3000 and 10000.. and that's right.. but what is the actual outcome? where is the problem?

Comment: Ohh well.. How do you pass two arguments in deposit function when it just accepts one?

Comment: Right now the code print out: Balance: 2000 Balance: 2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this might work for you

```
public class BankAccount {

  public static void main(String[] args) { 

      BankAccount account = new BankAccount();

      account.deposit(1000); 
      account.deposit(2000);
      System.out.println("Balance: " + account.getBalance()); 
      account.deposit(3000); 
      account.deposit(4000);
      System.out.println("Balance: " + account.getBalance());
  }

  private int currentBalance = 0;

  private int getBalance() {
      return this.currentBalance;
  }

  public void deposit(int depositAmount) {
      this.currentBalance = this.currentBalance + depositAmount;
  } 
}
```

Comment: or as suggested int the other answer.. use this.currentBalance += depositAmount for accumulation.

Answer (score 2):

Your deposit function is suspect. I think you want:

```
public void deposit(int depositAmount) {    
    this.currentBalance += depositAmount;
}
```

Note the `+=`: this will accumulate the deposit amount. You should also get rid of the class member `depositAmount` which is also causing bugs. Your `getBalance` function then reduces to

```
private/*ToDo - this will probably be public eventually*/ int getBalance() {
    return currentBalance;
}
```

Two more issues though:

1. This function `deposit` is not called directly since you are calling a version that also takes a string. (I'm assuming that the function you give is called eventually though).
2. How will you model decimal values? Don't use a floating point as that will be imprecise. Use a currency type instead.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but the second System.out.println gets the same result as the first one. :(

Answer (score 1):

You are actually adding everything to the same object `account` . hence you are getting the result of all values inside it .(i.e) sum of all inputs `10000`